# OpenMP - Using critical section inside two for loops

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to use `OpenMP 2.0` for `parallel for` for 2 `for` loops.I have found out some examples, how I can use `parallel for` and chose some variant.

That's why I'm trying to follow this way:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        //some code here..
    }
}
```

Okay. But I'm new in `OpenMP world` and I have understood that if I have some consturction, like: `if {...}`, I need to find another variants to parallelize my loops, and take into consideration my `if constructions`.

Can you help me to find a correct way in parallelizing my function using `OpenMP`? Thank you.

```
string readTextFromImage(Mat image) {
    string result = "";
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int ascii;
    char ch;


#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j < 3)
            {
                continue;
            }


            red = (image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] + 1 - 1) % 10;
            green = (image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] + 1 - 1) % 10;
            blue = (image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] + 1 - 1) % 10;

            if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 0)
            {
                return result;
            }


            ascii = red * 100 + green * 10 + blue;
            ch = ascii;
            result += ch;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

As my results using the code above. I have an error, my code doens't even compile:

> C1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

But if I use the code without `if` construction, I have a compiled code.

Comment: i dont understand the question. Your code has some `#pragma omp parallel for`. Is it not working as expected?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *"I have understood that if I have some consturction, like:"*? Also it would be great if you could provide [mcve], it makes a specific demonstration on how to do this correctly much easier.

Comment: @user463035818    No, it doesn't work. And I guess, It is because of not using `critical section`. Because I was testing it without `if` and it was okay. But sure, I need those conditions. And I'm trying to find a way how I should do for correct parallelizing.

Comment: @X21 please explain what is "doesn't work"

Comment: @user463035818  Does't work means that it doen't even run. And I have got error: `An internal error has occurred in the compiler.` But if I put that code without `if`. It's okay.

Comment: Please add the error verbatim to the question (after making sure that it is the code you posted that results in that error)

Comment: @Zulan         If I knew , how to provide `minimal correct` example, I would put it. But I ask for help to see how I should use `critical section`

Comment: maybe you misread. mcve is not "minimal correct.." but Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, where complete stands for "contains everything that is needed for someone else to copy the code and get the same error/behaviour"

Comment: @user463035818    Sorry, but I changed nothing to provide my code with the error.

Comment: yeah thats fine. I just wanted to make sure that you do understand the concept of a mcve. Actually you already have one there, one could argue about missing includes and no main, but thats nitpicking

Comment: @user463035818    Sometimes someone says that it's much to provide include and main, someone says that I need it. I can't guess. That's why I provided minimal things, how I think. Sorry.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned this yet: a message such as `C1001 An internal error has occurred in the compiler.` is evidence of a compiler bug.  Sometimes compiler bugs are exposed by a program attempting to do something extraordinary, so 'wrong' that the compiler-writers have either never encountered it before or expected never to happen so made no provision for.  As for OP's code, the much-asked for [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the funny/sad thing is that [MSCV's official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y19zxzb2.aspx) makes no mention of a bug in the compiler, instead it just suggests to *"Try rewriting the line where the error is reported, or several lines of code surrounding that line."*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues:

1. `return` is not allowed inside a `#pragma omp for`.
2. nested `#pragma omp for` are only allowed if you open a new parallel region
3. `result, ch, ascii, red, green, blue` are shared variables, you have to take account for this

In contrast to what you state: `if` statements are allowed inside `#pragma omp for`. The problem is only with `return, break`.